# PHP - Update a previous cookie to form an array

Tags: php, cookies

I have the following code:-

```
<?php 

if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
    $fav_cookie = array($_GET['job_fav']);
    $cookie_url = '/jobs/?job_fav=<?php the_ID(); ?>';

    if($job_fav !='') {
         setcookie(COOKIE_PREFIX . "job_fav",    " ", time() - 3600);
         setcookie(COOKIE_PREFIX . "job_fav", array($fav_cookie));
         header("Location: $cookie_url");
    }
?>

<a href="/jobs/?job_fav=<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="job-single-favourite icon-<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>
        <?php if (in_array(get_the_ID(), $fav_cookie)) {
                  echo ' starred-job';
              }
        ?>">
    </div>
</a><!-- none-logged-in starred-job -->

<?php } ?>
```

This is working fine, but it is only storing one value as a cookie at a time.

Basically what I am wanting to do is on click of the favourite icon it needs to store the job ID within the `$fav_cookie` array.

What is happening at the moment is that if you favourite a job `$fav_cookie` is being replaced by the new job ID. I somehow want to add each cookie inside the `$fav_cookie` array so it would become `113, 120, 234` for example, instead of replacing the ID each time.

If I haven't explained what I am wanting to achieve in great enough detail, let me know and I will amend my post.

**EDIT:--**

Just to add, the following works:-

```
$jobID = get_the_ID();
$jobListing = array(get_the_ID());
$html = '';
//$currentIDs = explode('|', $_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX . 'job_fav']);
$currentIDs = array('493','311');

var_dump($currentIDs);
foreach ($jobListing as $job) {

    $customClass = (in_array($jobID, $currentIDs)) ? ' starred-job' : '';

   // $html = '';
    $html .= '<a href="/jobs/?job_fav=' . htmlspecialchars($jobID) . '">';
    $html .= '<div class="job-single-favourite icon-' . htmlspecialchars($job_sector_html) . $customClass . '">';
    $html .= '</div></a>';
}


echo $html;
```

All I need now is $currentIDs to display be an array of the favourite jobs defined from $_COOKIE and it should be done.

`$currentIDs = explode('|', $_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX . 'job_fav']);` is an empty array

**EDIT 2**

Okay I now have the following:-

```
$jobID = get_the_ID();
$jobListing = array(get_the_ID());

$favourite_cookie = array($_GET['job_fav']);
$ids_string = implode('|', $favourite_cookie);
setcookie('job_fav', $ids_string);

var_dump($_COOKIE['job_fav']);


$ids_string = $_COOKIE['job_fav'];
$ids = explode('|', $_COOKIE['job_fav']);
<?php 
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {

$jobID = get_the_ID();
$jobListing = array(get_the_ID());
$html = '';
$currentIDs = explode('|', $_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX . 'job_fav']);
$currentIDs = $ids;

foreach ($jobListing as $job) {

    $customClass = (in_array($jobID, $currentIDs)) ? ' starred-job' : '';

    $html = '';
    $html .= '<a href="/jobs/?job_fav=' . htmlspecialchars($jobID) . '">';
    $html .= '<div class="job-single-favourite icon-' . htmlspecialchars($job_sector_html) . $customClass . '">';
    $html .= '</div></a>';
}


echo $html;

} ?>
```

And now have two issues:-

- When I favourite a job, I have to click twice in order for it to update.
- $_COOKIE['job_fav'] gets replaced with the new job ID every time you favourite a different job, instead of adding it to the array

Comment: So you don't want to set several cookie (as title states) but update a previous one?

Comment: That is correct @ÁlvaroGonzález - sorry the title was misleading

Comment: $cookie_url is bad. you cannot embed php code blocks inside other php code blocks...you're passing the literal characters `<`, `?`, `p`, etc... as the `job_fav` query value. and your'e setting the SAME cookie name, so the new value replaces the previous one. cookies also cannot store arrays. they're just a text string. you'd have to encode/serialize your array, save/retrieve it from the cookie, decode/unserialize, mod it, recode, then re-save

Comment: Maybe put data into an array and use serialize() and unserialize()?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690537/how-do-you-set-a-php-cookie-with-multiple-values?rq=1

Comment: _"Cookies names can be set as array names and will be available to your PHP scripts as arrays but separate cookies are stored on the user's system. Consider explode() to set one cookie with multiple names and values. It is not recommended to use serialize() for this purpose, because it can result in security holes."_ May be relevant in terms of not using `serialize()`, taken from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: please add `get_the_ID()` code and explains what does `$job_fav` var contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `implode` and `explode` when creating/retrieving the `$_COOKIE`.

So for example when you want to create/update the list of IDs within the `$_COOKIE` you would first explode the current `$_COOKIE` if set.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX . 'job_fav'])) {
    $jobIDs   = explode('|', $_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX . 'job_fav']);
    $jobIDs[] = $_GET['job_fav']; // Add new ID to the list.

    // We store them as a string, that we can explode when needed.
    setcookie(COOKIE_PREFIX . "job_fav", implode('|', $jobIDs)); 
}
```

If you ever want to turn the `$_COOKIE` into the array format, you just do:

`explode('|', $_COOKIE['job_fav']);`

I believe that you give you a good idea of how you can store it. Any questions, just let me know.

**Edit:** I had a few spare minutes, I tried to implement it/clean up your code a little. Not sure if I got it all right but it's at least something for you to work off:

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {

    $id          = the_ID();
    $favouriteID = $_GET['job_fav'];
    $cookieURL   = '/jobs/?job_fav=' . $id;

    $currentIDs  = []; // Storage Array.

    // If the user has the $_COOKIE set already.
    if (isset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX . 'job_fav'])) {
        $currentIDs = explode('|', $_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX . 'job_fav']);

        // Append the new ID.
        $currentIDs[] = $favouriteID;
        setcookie(COOKIE_PREFIX . 'job_fav', implode('|', $currentIDs));
        header('Location: ' . $cookieURL);
        exit;
    }

    $currentIDs[] = $favouriteID;
    setcookie(COOKIE_PREFIX . 'job_fav', implode('|', $currentIDs));

    // Build up the HTML.
    $html  = '';
    $html .= '<a href="/jobs/?job_fav=' . htmlspecialchars($id) . '">';
    $html .= '<div class="job-single-favourite icon-' . htmlspecialchars($job_sector_html);
    if (in_array($id, $currentIDs)) {
        $html .= ' starred-job';
    }
    $html .= '">';
    $html .= '</div></a>';

    echo $html;
}
```

Can see it here: https://ideone.com/ivxRAT

There are multiple other ways to clean up the above, but without knowing your code base and what the `get_ID()` and `get_the_ID()` functions are doing it's hard for me to do it. Really if these are just returning the same ID for each instance each time, you may as well call it once at the top, store it in a variable and use that when query whether the ID exists in the array, etc.

**Edit2:** No idea why your code isn't working, the logic works fine for me, it will now store multiple `$_COOKIES` as shown in the ideone.

So I can only presume that your problem is how you're then using your `$_COOKIE` to decide whether you need to apply the styles or not.

So since I have no idea about how you are doing this, I can only guess.

I'm *guessing* somewhere you have a database query that pulls out all your current jobs. I'm also guessing that you loop through that data to print them out to the page. So here is what I would suggest:

```
$jobListing = <PULLDATAFROMDATABASE>

$html = '';
$currentIDs = explode('|', $_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX . 'job_fav']);
foreach ($jobListing as $job) {

    $customClass = (in_array($job->id, $currentIDs)) ? ' starred-job' : '';

    $html .= '<a href="/jobs/?job_fav=' . htmlspecialchars($id) . '">';
    $html .= '<div class="job-single-favourite icon-' . htmlspecialchars($job_sector_html) . $customClass . '">';
    $html .= '</div></a>';
}

echo $html
```

**Edit3:**

How to set the cookies:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4);
$ids_string = implode('|', $ids);
setcookie('job_fav', $ids_string);
```

How to get the cookies:

```
$ids_string = $_COOKIE['job_fav'];
$ids = explode('|', $_COOKIE['job_fav']);
```

So if we do: `print_r($ids);`

We get:

> Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )

**Edit3:**

The first part.

```
$jobID        = get_the_ID();
$jobListing   = array(get_the_ID());
$favouriteIDs = array();

$favourite_cookie = $_GET['job_fav']; // This is the new id we want to add to the array?
if (isset($_COOKIE['job_fav'])) {
    $favouriteIDs = explode('|', $_COOKIE['job_fav']);
}
$favouriteIDs[] = $_GET['job_fav']; // Append the new ID onto the array.
setcookie('job_fav', implode('|', $favouriteIDs));

var_dump($_COOKIE['job_fav']);
```

The other part

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {

    $jobID        = get_the_ID();
    $jobListing   = array(get_the_ID());
    $html         = '';
    $favouriteIDs = explode('|', $_COOKIE['job_fav']);

    foreach ($jobListing as $job) {

        $customClass = (in_array($jobID, $favouriteIDs)) ? ' starred-job' : '';

        $html = '';
        $html .= '<a href="/jobs/?job_fav=' . htmlspecialchars($jobID) . '">';
        $html .= '<div class="job-single-favourite icon-' . htmlspecialchars($job_sector_html) . $customClass . '">';
        $html .= '</div></a>';
    }

    echo $html;
}
```

Don't know if there's something strange going on in your code, but you randomly added Opening/Closing PHP tags. If they need to be there for some reason and this isn't the full code following on from one another, you can add them back in.

Comment: Thanks @Virtual Pigeon - Although when I var_dump($html); I get a result like '311311string(78)' ?

Comment: @nsilva Can you clarify what the `the_id()` and `get_the_id()` functions do, and what they return for me please?

Comment: `get_the_id()` and `the_id()` are both the same, they both get the unique ID of the job, e.g. job id = '130'. If it helps, here is the link to the job listings which has the 'favourite' function on there (which on the site, you can only favourite one job at the time as this is the original code): http://distinctrecruitment.com/jobs

Comment: @nsilva I've made some edits, it seems to be working for me, although I had to fake the methods and the `$job_sector_html` bit which I presume you have defined elsewhere because it isn't defined in your example. All the same though, the concept you need is to `explode()` and `implode()` the array to strings and back when storing inside a cookie.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply @Virtual Pigeon, I've tried to updated code. Now what happens is that it displays an extra star for every job now. So for job one it shows 1 star, job 2 it shows 2 stars, and so on. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @nsilva Try adding `$html = ''` before the first bit of HTML, i'll update my example with it. That should fix the problem I believe.

Comment: I've done that @Virtual Pigeon - now it only 'favourites' one job at a time; http://distinctrecruitment.com/jobs/

Comment: @nsilva I've got no idea then, the logic works for me, the `$_COOKIE` now stores multiple values. So I can only presume the error is coming from how you are presenting the data in your code. I have no clue about how the rest of your code is functioning so its impossible for me to guess fixes unfortunately. I've put an example of what you can do but you have access to your code, I do not. You're going to have to do some experimenting yourself. You've got a solution to your initial problem of how to store 'Arrays' in `$_COOKIES` now at least.

Comment: Made an edit to the question @Virtual Pigeon (nearly there now)

Comment: @nsilva If you check your stored cookies, what is the cookie saved as which contains the IDs?

Comment: I'm no longer storing any cookies so $COOKIE['job_fav'] is null

Comment: @nsilva Strange, i've added how to Set/Get the cookies at the bottom in a new edit. That logic works, so it's just a case of you replacing a few bits.

Comment: Thanks @Virtual Pigeon, I've updated the question again, still having problems getting this to work. Every time you favourite a job the job ID gets passed by `job_fav` - no idea how I can get this to 'add' to the array every time you favourite a new job

Comment: When adding at an array you need to push the element on, you're just overwriting by the looks of it in yours i.e. `$array[] = 'somevar';` will append `somevar` to the end of the `$array` element. I've updated my answer again, that _should_ fix it. I have no clue what your doing with the `get_the_ID()` function but it looks fairly odd. You also used the `COOKIE_PREFIX` constant for one area but not the other.

Comment: awesome thanks @Virtual Pigeon - finally got it working, only issue I'm having now is that I have to refresh the page for the favourite to appear, any ideas? I've awarded you the 50+, you've helped me a lot already, really appreciated it :)

Comment: @nsilva You could 'fake' the favourite initially, so have some JQuery that adds/removes the style on click of a star. That way the stars will appeared as the end user would expect. The other way would probably be to use AJAX although i'm not 100% sure how you would implement that cleanly without a fairly large re-write of how you handle favourites.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: your original example wouldn't work. setcookie expects a string as the value, you need to serialize the data. Answer updated.

You need to get the current value of the cookie and append the new value to the array. Try something like this.

```
$cookies = array();
if (!empty($_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX . "job_fav"])) {
  $cookies = $_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX . "job_fav"];
  $cookies = unserialize($cookies);
}
$cookies[] = $fav_cookie;
setcookie(COOKIE_PREFIX . "job_fav", serialize($cookies));
```

Then when you need the cookie values:

```
$job_favs = unserialize($_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX . "job_fav"]);
```

Comment: Just tried and it is still only saving 1 favourite at a time

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo (extra 's'). Try again.

OP said that their example was working using an array in set_cookie. All I'm suggesting is adding the new value to the current value.  The current cookie value would be available in the super global $_COOKIE.

Comment: Thanks @ChanceG although it doesn't seem to be working still, still doing one job at a time, and if I navigate to /jobs/ without a job_fav, no values are 'favourited'

Comment: Thanks again @ChanceG - I don't understand why $job_favs returns bool(false) with the updated code though